# How to get list of users by tag ordered by number of answers?

Tags: support, top-users

If we go to the top users list for a particular tag (say [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/topusers)), the ranking is ordered by the total score of users on that tag. How can we show the list ordered by number of posts?

Comment: I believe you'll need to use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that. The site UI doesn't provide any way to change the sort order. Perhaps start here: [How can I retrieve list of top 100 users on Stack Exchange for a specific tag sorted by posted content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327317/how-can-i-retrieve-list-of-top-100-users-on-stack-exchange-for-a-specific-tag-so) If you're lucky, rene will come by and write a queue to specifically answer your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As predicted by Cody, you're lucky.

Here is the [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1352614?qa=2&tagname=sql).

Notice that you need to provide a tagname and whether you want answers or questions as the ranking. That is similar to what is shown on the top users page.

```sql
-- qa:1 for questions, 2 for answers
select rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rank
     , owneruserid [User Link]
     , count(*) [Number of posts] 
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where owneruserid is not null
and communityowneddate is null
and p.posttypeid = ##qa:int?2##
and t.tagname = ##tagname:string?sql##
group by owneruserid
order by count(*) desc
```

When run today (with the restore for this week still going) this is the result:

[image: users league for SQL]

Careful observers will notice that the count reported here is off compared to that is in top 30 list on the tag page. I suspect this is due to synonyms and/or other data errors, not because the query is screwed.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: Cool, I had no idea I was so high on the python list!

Comment: It's worth noting that quality ≠ quantity.

Comment: Is "Gordon Linoff" the sum of the column?